# LeetCode: 3Sum, Getting AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL Error

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers

I tried this problem on my PC in Eclipse, and it is working fine. But, it is crashing when I am trying it in [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/) and I don't understand why.

I am getting the error `"AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL"` on LeetCode. And I can not debug it on the site, because I do not have a premium account.

In the problem, I am asked to find a solution for:

> Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.
> Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

Here is my code:

```
 #include "common.h"


int** threeSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize, int** returnColumnSizes) {
    /**
     * Return an array of arrays of size *returnSize.
     * The sizes of the arrays are returned as *returnColumnSizes array.
     * Note: Both returned array and *columnSizes array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
     */
    int ii;
    bubble_sort(nums, numsSize);
    int **arr = (int**) calloc(numsSize* 3, sizeof(int*));
//  for (ii = 0; ii < numsSize; ii++)
//      arr[ii] =  (int*) calloc(3, sizeof(int));
    *returnSize = 0;
    int i, low, high = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int target = 0;

    for  (i = 0; nums[i] <= 0 && i < numsSize -2;) {
        low = i + 1;
        high = numsSize - 1;

        while ( low < high) {
            sum = nums[i] + nums[low] + nums[high];
            if (sum > target)
                high--;
            else if (sum < target)
                low++;
            else {
                *returnSize += 1;
                arr[*returnSize-1] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
                arr[*returnSize-1][0] = nums[i];
                arr[*returnSize-1][1] = nums[low];
                arr[*returnSize-1][2] = nums[high];
                do high--; while(nums[high] == nums[high+1] && low < high);
            }

        }
        do i++; while (nums[i]==nums[i-1] && i < numsSize-2);
    }

    return arr;
}

void run_3sum() {
    printf("\n ---------- Run 3Sum ----------- \n");
    int n = 8;
    int i = 0;
    int* returnSize = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    int** returnColumnSizes = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int));;
    int **res;
    int arr[8] = {-10, 0, 10, 2, -2, 5, 3, -8};//{-2,0,1,2,-1,3};

    int *nums = (int*) calloc(n+4, sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            *nums = arr[i];
            nums++;
        }
    nums = nums - i;
    res = threeSum(nums, n, returnSize, returnColumnSizes);
    printf("\n Results ---3sum ---\n");
    printf_3sum(res, *returnSize, 3);
}
```

Comment: `int** returnColumnSizes = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int));;` looks odd, but you do not use this variable at all, so why don't you remove it?

Comment: yes, I can remove it, I keep it cause it is in the signature of the function on LeetCode.
On LeetCode, the problems seems to be at sort function.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues in your implementation. The most important reason is, you did not initialize and use `int** returnColumnSizes` inside the `threeSum()` function. You have to initialize and set values to `int** returnColumnSizes`. If there is no need of this variable, then leetcode should not pass this as a function parameter. Let's first understand the purpose of `returnColumnSizes`. Lets fist understand the function signature of `threeSum`:

- The function's return type is `int**`. Meaning, this function will return a pointer of pointers (a pointer will point to the starting pointer of an array).
- Parameter `int* nums` indicates the input array.
- Parameter `int numsSize` indicates the size of the `nums` array.
- Parameter `int* returnSize` indicates the size of the array the returning pointer points to.
- Parameter `int** returnColumnSizes` indicates the size of inner arrays of the returning pointer.

Here is a sample input and output form this problem:

```
Input: nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]
Output: [[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]
```

Now, pay attention to the output. The output is an array of arrays (which is basically pointer of pointers). Now, for this output `returnSize` will be `2` and `returnColumnSizes` will be an array of size `2` and it will represent like this:

```
int** returnColumnSizes = [3, 3]
```

This represents the number of elements the inner pointers of the returning pointer is pointing to. Now as you were not setting this value inside the `threeSum()` function, the program raises this error as it was not sure how much it will read data from the pointer. Here I have fixed the issue:

```
int** threeSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize, int** returnColumnSizes) {
    /**
     * Return an array of arrays of size *returnSize.
     * The sizes of the arrays are returned as *returnColumnSizes array.
     * Note: Both returned array and *columnSizes array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
     */
    int ii;
    bubble_sort(nums, numsSize);
    
    *returnSize=0;
    int **arr=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * numsSize);
    *returnColumnSizes=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numsSize);
    
    int i, low, high = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int target = 0;

    for  (i = 0; nums[i] <= 0 && i < numsSize -2;) {
        low = i + 1;
        high = numsSize - 1;

        while ( low < high) {
            sum = nums[i] + nums[low] + nums[high];
            if (sum > target)
                high--;
            else if (sum < target)
                low++;
            else {
                (*returnColumnSizes)[*returnSize]=3;
                arr[*returnSize] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
                arr[*returnSize][0] = nums[i];
                arr[*returnSize][1] = nums[low];
                arr[*returnSize][2] = nums[high];
                (*returnSize) += 1;
                do high--; while(nums[high] == nums[high+1] && low < high);
            }
        }
        do i++; while (nums[i]==nums[i-1] && i < numsSize-2);
    }
    
    return arr;
}
```

There are other couple of issues in your solution as well. For example, the size of `int **arr` should be adjusted dynamically, otherwise it will allocate more memory than required. A general practice to handle this issue is, you should start with a lower number of memory and if needed you increase the size of this array by doubling it each time. [Here](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/discuss/342803/runtime-128-ms-faster-than-7723-of-c-online-submissions-for-3sum) you will find a more efficient solution of this problem written in `C`.